# Exibindo datas em formulários

Tags: php, html5, formulário, data

Estou criando um formulário que contém um campo cujo tipo de dados é DATE, aonde eu desejo que seja retornado por padrão um determinado valor. Porém não há o que eu faça para que isso ocorra. Meu código é esse:

```
<?php $ini = date('d-m-Y'); ?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="inicio" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666666;">
  De</label> <input type="date" name="date_form" id="inicio" size="7" value="<?php echo $ini; ?>" /> 
   a
  <label for="label">Fim</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="label" />
</form>
```

Comment: bom campo tipo date recebe um tipo especifico de formatação que não lembro agora para te passar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na formatação da data. Para que o campo reconheça o valor que você deseja exibir, o mesmo precisa estar no formato `YYYY-mm-dd`. Veja:

```html
Errado: <input type="date" value="13-09-2017">
Certo: <input type="date" value="2017-09-13">
```

Então basta alterar a chamada da função `date` no PHP:

```
$ini = date("Y-m-d");
```

> Lembrando que nem todos os navegadores podem ter o mesmo comportamento para um campo `type="date"`, como mostrado no site [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime).